# get distance between two markers agm-direction

Tags: angular

I have tried everyting but I couldnt get the distance between two points (the path we path not direct distance)
I have tried to get travelMode and I couldnt do it, please I need help. Thanks for everything

```js
  public renderOptions = {
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions: { 
      strokeColor: 'blue',
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      strokeWeight: 4 } 
}
public renderOptions1 = {
  suppressMarkers: true,
  polylineOptions: { 
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    strokeWeight: 4 } 
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Teslim Alınacak Konum<span role="button" (click)="modal.dismiss('');" style="float: right;" class="fas fa-times fs-20"></span></h4>
        <agm-map [zoom]="12"  style="height:500px" [latitude]="(mapAlinacakX+mapEdilecekX)/2" [longitude]="(mapAlinacakY+mapEdilecekY)/2">
          <agm-direction 
          [origin]="anaMerkez" 
          [destination]="alimYeri"
          [renderOptions]="renderOptions" 
          [markerOptions]="markerOptions"
        >
        </agm-direction>
        <agm-direction 
          [origin]="teslimYeri" 
          [destination]="anaMerkez"
          [renderOptions]="renderOptions1" 
          [markerOptions]="markerOptions1"
        >
        </agm-direction>
        </agm-map>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following package for get distance from two different coordinates

https://www.npmjs.com/package/haversine-distance

OR you can use ready made function which i have pasted below (convert to TS if needed..)

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```